# What's the meaning of the Johnson filtration in terms of configuration spaces?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, mapping-class-groups, configuration-spaces

This question is inspired of course by the remarkable paper of [Tetsuhiro Moriyama](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/jlms/jdm077/abstract) from 2008.

Let $\Sigma$ be a genus $g \geq 3$ **closed** surface.

Let $\phi : \Sigma \to \Sigma$ be an orientation preserving diffeomorphism. We assume that $\phi$ acts as the identity on cohomology (i.e. it is in the Torelli group).

- Assume that $\phi$ lies in level $k_1 \geq 1$ of the Johnson filtration but not in level $k_1+1$.
- Assume that there exists $k \geq 1$ such that the action of $\phi$ on $H^*(Conf_{k}(\Sigma);\mathbb{Z})$ the homology of configuration space of $k$ points is trivial. Let $k_2$ the maximal such $k$.

**Question.** What is the relation between $k_1$ and $k_2$? (i.e. does one bound the other)

Comment: The title has no relationship with the question.  You should make it more descriptive.

Comment: What is the "Johnson filtration"?

Comment: @AndyPutman OK, sure. Fixed.

Comment: @DylanWilson It's a filtration on the Torelli group defined by studying the effect a diffeomorphism has on nilpotent quotients of $\pi_1$of the surface. A good survey is Section 5 in Morita's [Structure of the mapping class groups of surfaces: a survey and a prospect](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911258), Richard Hain's [Infinitesimal presentations of the Torelli group](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1997-10-03/S0894-0347-97-00235-X/S0894-0347-97-00235-X.pdf) or Andy's book-in-progress on the Torelli group (appears in his webpage).